# Wordpress - Duplication in categories and sub-categories of the Divi theme menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

Hello Wordpress Community !

I currently have a problem on wordpress with the number of sub-categories displayed in the menu of my website.
I currently want to put text above my sub-categories, here is the expected visual in HTML:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
  <span or div  or div class="menu-text">Text </span or /div>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub-categories 2 AA-1 </a></li>
  <span or div  class="menu-text">Text 0</span or /div >
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub-categories  AA-2 </a></li>
  <span or div  class="menu-text">Text 1</span or /div >
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub-categories  AA-4 </a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub-categories  AA-9 </a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub-categories  AA-10 </a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub-categories  AA-11 </a></li>
  <span or div  class="menu-text">Text 2</span or /div >
   <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub-categories  AA-5 </a></li>
   <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub-categories  AA-6 </a></li>
   <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub-categories  AA-7 </a></li>
   <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub-categories  AA-8 </a></li>
  <span or div  class="menu-text">Text 3</span or /div >
   <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub-categories  AA-8 </a></li>
  <span or div  class="menu-text">Text 4</span or /div>
   <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub-categories  AA-9 </a></li>
</ul>
```

1. Initially, like any good wordpress site, I edited my sub-categories on the dashboard > wordpress menu.

2)As far as I know, is that I have to work on Divi's header.php file in order to integrate my class="menu-text" because I can't integrate them via the Wordpress > Menu dashboard. So I edited a php code that I integrated into my header.php.
Here is the header.php code:

```
<ul id="top-menu" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $menuClass ); ?>">

<?php if ( 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_home_link' ) ) { ?>
<li <?php if ( is_home() ) echo( 'class="current_page_item"' ); ?>><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Home', 'Divi' ); ?></a></li>
<?php }; ?>

<?php show_page_menu( $menuClass, false, false ); ?>
<?php show_categories_menu( $menuClass, false ); ?>
</ul>
<?php
 else :
 $modified_nav = str_replace('<ul class="sub-menu">', '<ul class="sub-menu">
   <?php if (is_hover_menu()) && is_category("Categorie 1")) : ?> 
   <div class="menu-text"><i>Text:</i></div>
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-50 et-show-dropdown et-hover"><a href="../">Sub-categories 1 AA-1</a></li>
   <div class="menu-text">Text 1:</div>
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-74 et-show-dropdown et-hover"><a href="../>Sub-categories 2 AA-2</a></li>
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-79 et-show-dropdown et-hover"><a href="../">Sub-categories 3 AA-3</a></li>
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-80 et-show-dropdown et-hover"><a href="../">Sub-categories 4 AA-4</a></li>
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-81 et-show-dropdown et-hover"><a href="../">Sub-categories 5 AA-5</a></li>
   <div class="menu-text">Text 2 :</div>
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-49 et-show-dropdown et-hover"><a href="../">Sub-categories 6 AA-6</a></li>
   <div class="menu-text">Text 3 :</div>
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7 et-show-dropdown et-hover"><a href="../">Sub-categories 7 AA-7</a></li>
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-77 et-show-dropdown et-hover"><a href="../">Sub-categories 8 AA-8</a></li>
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-76 et-show-dropdown et-hover"><a href="../">Sub-categories 9 AA-9</a></li>
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-75 et-show-dropdown et-hover"><a href="../">Sub-categories 10 AA-10</a></li>
   <div class="menu-text">Text 4 :</div>
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-78 et-show-dropdown et-hover"><a href="../">Sub-categories 11 AA-11</a></li>
   <div class="menu-text">Texte 5 :</div>
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-72 et-show-dropdown et-hover"><a href="../">Sub-categories 12 AA-12</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>', $primaryNav);
                              
echo et_core_esc_wp($modified_nav);
endif;
?>
</nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

MAIN PROBLEM :

1. The main problem regarding [Dashboard wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcHNg.png) and header.php files, s that it will create duplicate content for my website.
   2)The second problem is that by removing my sub-categories (Dashboard > menu), I disable the hoover display function for my sub-categories and therefore for my "menu-text".

- Should I only use the header.php (I think so because if I want to add my "menu-text" I have no choice?
- Or is it still possible to generate the menu via (Dashboard > Menu) and only add the "menu-text" text to my php files (probably header.php too)?

N.B: I don't want to add a menu plugin, even if coding in hard code doesn't conform to wordpress, because I want to optimise my website as much as possible, as there won't be any changes to the menu in the future.